# General Solution of second order differential equation ${\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}}+{\frac {dy}{dx}} = x^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

${\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}}+{\frac {dy}{dx}} = x^2$

I'm not sure how to solve it, in textbook solution for this problem is

$y = \frac13x^3 - x^2 + 2x +c_1+c_2e^{-x}$

Comment: What is your experience with linear second order differential equations? have you covered the concepts of a particular and complementary solution ?

Comment: I have learnt linear first order and quadratic second order approximation and don't have much experience with linear second order differential equations. Would it be similar to Initial value problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution would be $v=y'$ and then it becomes $v'+v=x^2$ which has an integrating factor of $e^x$ which makes it $\left (ve^x\right )'=x^2e^x$ and integrating both sides $ve^x=e^x(x^2-2x+2)+C_1$ and then we get $v=y'=x^2-2x+2+C_1e^{-x}$ $$\boxed{y=\frac{1}{3}x^3-x^2+2x+C_1e^{-x}+C_2}$$ I didn't really understand the whole kernel thing from the previous answer. I apologize to the severe incorrectness of my last answer.

Comment: when you integrate on both side, shouldn't that be $$ve^x=e^x\frac{x^3}{3}+e^xx^2+c_1$$ $$v=\frac{x^3}{3}+x^2+c_1e^{-1}$$

Comment: @Reboot you need to integrate $x^2 e^x$ by parts and then through simplification you get a fairly nice answer

Comment: My apologies, I differentiate the equation instead of integration.

Answer (score 1):

I want to show you the 'classical' method to solve these inhomogeneous linear ODEs of second order.

$$y''(x)+y'(x) = x^2$$

We solve this ODE with the ansatz $y(x)=y_h(x)+y_p(x)$ where $y_h$ denotes the solution to the corresponding homogeneous problem and $y_p$ is some particular solution to this ODE.

Firstly let's look at the homogenous problem $y''(x)+y'(x)=0$. We look for an exponential solution i.e. let's set $y=c e^{\lambda x}$ for some constant $c$. We get the so called characteristic equation

$$\lambda^2+\lambda=\lambda(\lambda+1)=0$$

i.e. $\lambda \in \{-1,0 \}$. Therefore we have $y_h(x)=c_1+c_2 e^{-x}$ where $c_1,c_2$ are some constants.

Now for the particular solution. It is quite nice that the inhomogeneous right hand side is a polynomial of second order - corresponding to this let's set $y_p$ as a polynomial, in particular $y_p(x):=a_0+a_1 x+ a_2x^2+a_3x^3.$ Now, plugging this into the ODE we get

$$\begin{align}(2a_2+6a_3x)+(a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2)&=x^2 \\
\Leftrightarrow x^0(a_1+2a_2)+x^1(2a_2+6a_3)+x^2(3a_3)&=x^0 \cdot 0 + x^1 \cdot 0 +x^2 \cdot 1\end{align}$$

Therefore we have to solve the linear equation system

$$\begin{cases} a_1+2a_2 &= 0 \\ 2a_2+6a_3 &=0 \\ 3a_3&=1\end{cases}$$

and that means $a_3=\frac13, a_2=-1, a_1=2$. Further $a_0$ is arbitrary, so let's just set $a_0=0$ since we just look for one particular solution. We get finally $y_p(x)=\frac13 x^3-x^2+2x.$

All in all we have

> $$y(x)=y_h(x)+y_p(x)=c_1+c_2 e^{-x}+\frac13 x^3-x^2+2x$$

Comment: Thanks you very much, It is very easy to follow. I also found the similar explanation in the textbook.

Answer (score -1):

Integrate once to get $$\frac{dy}{dx} + y = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + c_1.$$ Formally this is $$(D+I)y = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + c_1$$ with the derivative $D$. Since $(I+D)(I - D + D^2 - D^3) = I - D^4$ acts as $I$ on polynomials of degree $3$ it follows that \begin{align*} y &= (I-D+D^2-D^3) \Big( \frac{1}{3}x^3 + c_1 \Big) + \mathrm{Ker}(D+I) \\ &= \frac{1}{3}x^3 - x^2 + 2x - 2 + c_1 + \mathrm{Ker}(D+I) \\ &= \frac{1}{3}x^3 - x^2 + 2x + c_1 + c_2 e^{-x} \end{align*} since the kernel of $D+I$ is $\{f: f' + f = 0\} = \{c_2 e^{-x}: \, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}.$